# Distinctive Addition

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Since my previous cute, easy number puzzle turned out to be a duplicate, I felt I needed to redeem myself.

$2+9 = 6$
$7+8 = 8$
$9+6 = 5$
$0+9 = 6$
$1+4 = 6$
$9+9 = 3$
$2+6 = 6$
$6+4 = 7$
$1+5 = 6$

@TroyAndAbed:
$12+27 = 8$

What does:
$5+5 = ?$
Why?

Hopefully isn't too hard, please ask if you need any test cases.

HINT 1

> Use the title of the question

Comment: I hope it isn't 10 ;-p

Comment: If 5+5 isn't 10 I am in trouble for my upcoming 2nd grade math test...

Comment: Any chance this uses equivalence classes?

Comment: Is 12 + 27  possible or does it works only with number < 10?

Comment: @Goinghamateur It doesn't involve equivalence classes.

Comment: @TroyAndAbed, 12+27 = 8

Comment: How are things done here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How many total letters are used at least once in the spellings of the words
>  So 5+5= 4

That is a strong hint

Comment: Ya, I couldn't think of a more moderate hint

Comment: Also I was nervous because of all my down votes :(

Comment: Yeah with pure mathematical questions to get upvotes you need to weave it into a story it seems, feels more organic too.